# Server-side RequiredFieldValidators not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, server-side, validation

I have a form representing a survey that is dynamically generated based on some database configuration.   I have a custom server control for rendering the survey (`SurveyRenderer`) which contains custom server controls for rendering questions (`QuestionRenderers`).  I dynamically add `RequiredFieldValidators` for questions if they are flagged as being required.  I add these validators to the `SurveyRenderer`'s control collection.

The gist of the code...

```
// In SurveyRenderer.CreateChildControls()...
foreach (QuestionRenderer questionRenderer in questionRenderers)
{
   if (questionRenderer.Question.IsRequired)
   {
       Controls.Add(CreateRequiredValidator(questionRenderer));
   }
}
```

The client-side validation works fine -- if someone has omitted a required question, the validators catch it and the form doesn't validate.  However if I turn off JavaScript and submit an invalid form, the validators do not seem to work.

On the server-side I am calling `Page.Validate()` and checking `Page.IsValid` in the submit button click event handler.  Despite submitting a form where required questions have been left blank - something that would be caught client-side - on the server-side `Page.IsValid` remains `True`.

```
// In SurveyPage.aspx...
public void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Page.Validate();
   if (Page.IsValid)
   {
       // Always get here, even though the form is not valid and would
       // have been caught client-side...
   }
}
```

Should I be adding the validators to the Page's Control collection, rather than the SurveyRenderer?  How come it works on the client-side but not server-side?

**UPDATE**: My QuestionRenderer is annotated with:

```
[ValidationProperty("IsValid")]
```

And the IsValid get method is like so:

```
// QuestionRenderer.IsValid
public bool IsValid
{
    get
    {
        EnsureChildControls();
        if (Question.IsRequired && QuestionIsNotAnswered())
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

If I set a breakpoint and step through, I can see that `QuestionRenderer.IsValid` is being fired OK.  It is returning `false` when it should do.  If I go fine-grained and call in btn_submitClick:

```
// In SurveyPage.aspx...
public void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (IValidator validator in Page.Validators)
    {
        validator.Validate();  // this calls through to QuestionRenderer.IsValid, which returns false...
        bool valIsValid = validator.IsValid; // yet this is set to True
    }
}
```

So validator.IsValid is true, even though the call to QuestionRenderer.IsValid returns false.  So maybe I haven't wired something up correctly?  Is using   `[ValidationProperty("IsValid")]` not enough?

Comment: when calling `validator.Validate()` explicitely, does your handler get fired or not?

Comment: @Andreas: Yes, the QuestionRenderer.IsValid handler does get fired when calling validator.Validate().

Comment: please read the last comment of my answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually, validation uses `Page.Validators` where all the validators are stored (the actual routine is quity tricky) - so it does not matter, where you add them.

source of `BaseValidator`

```
protected internal override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    this.Page.Validators.Add(this);
}
```

i would leave them in th view, as you could use `object sender`-parameter (which represents the validator) to get the associated control ...

i believe, your `CreateChildControls` - which does the attaching of the validators - is called to late, so it misses the validation phase ...
could you maybe try to call `EnsureChildControls` in `OnLoad`-event, to see if it changes something?
another chance might be, that your validators are not visible or disabled...

**EDIT**

according to your edits, i would encourage you to use a `CustomValidator` - a `RequiredFieldValidator` will return `true` on each case (property is `true` or `false`), because it is not empty :)

Comment: Thanks Andreas -- I've tried adding EnsureChildControls in both OnInit and OnLoad, but still Page.IsValid is coming up as true.

Comment: could you add some logging in the validation-event to see, if it is fired or not? btw are you working with validationGroups?

Comment: Thanks Andreas -- I've updated my originally question to answer your question.  I've used ValidationProperty to specify which method on the QuestionRenderer control should be used -- is this what you mean by the validation event?  If I step through in the debugger, it seems like this fires OK, but something is wrong as the validator.IsValid still returns true.  No, I'm not using validationGroups.

Comment: @ngm: you may need to set the `AssociatedControl`-property if you are working with the `ValidationProperty`-attribute

Comment: @Andreas: Do you mean `AssociatedControlId` property of BaseValidator?  According to MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.associatedcontrolid.aspx) "This property is not supported." except for Label.

Comment: @ngm: sorry ... i meant `ControlToValidate` ... :)

Comment: @Andreas: ah, yep -- I'm already using `ControlToValidate` :)

Comment: @Andreas --- ahhhhh, that makes sense!  D'oh.  I'll give that a try.

Comment: My quick solution for now was to keep using RequiredFieldValidator, but to set the ControlToValidate on one of the child controls that I have in QuestionRenderer, rather than the QuestionRenderer itself.  As all I'm really validating for now is to check that some response has been left, it makes sense to reuse the existing validator I guess.  If my validation logic gets more complex I'll make a custom validator.  Thanks for the help @Andreas :)